# How to find iframe on google captcha test page with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I am trying to get to the iframe on this page: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo. this is the iframe with images that you have to click. iframe shows up then you click on the "i'm not a robot" button. you have to use selenium for this to work, it won't work if you do it manually in chrome.

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo')
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-demo"]/div/div/iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('recaptcha-checkbox').click()
#choose new iframe with pictures - doesn't work
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/iframe')
```

what is the problem here?
tnx, vasja

Comment: Whatever you're imagining won't work. Are you thinking you can click on the streetlights / crosswalks programatically?

Comment: @pguardiario _... click on the streetlights / crosswalks programatically..._ is not a part of the OP's question either, as you are speculating. Please give a chance to the contributors to learn how to handle elements with in `<iframe>` tags, of coarse _captcha_ can reside with in an `<iframe>`.

Comment: @pguardiario Please read the question again. The question heading is loud and clear **find iframe on google captcha test page with python selenium** but not to bypass **google captcha**. OP's requirement and your visibility are miles apart.

Comment: there's no iframe on the page you linked to... Just a note that when using Selenium, the captcha will keep re-displaying endlessly.  (you can't solve it)